# r2dbc classcast exception when updating existing entity

Tags: database, postgresql, kotlin, reactive, r2dbc

Currently experiencing classcast exception while trying to update entity using spring r2dbc repository like this:

```
r2dbc.save(entity).awaitSingle()
```

the same code works fine when I am saving new entity with Id field being null, but when I prefill it to update already existing entity I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
```

Also have to say that the targeted entity updates, seems like the problem accrues when r2dbc tries to get the response entity

```
@Table(name = "entity", schema = "entity")
data class Entity(
    @Id
    val id: Long?,

CREATE TABLE entity.entity
(
    id                     BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
```

also have to note that entity data class does not implement Persistable<> interface